# slightly blurred text and bitmaps AFTER 3d transformation

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, flash-cs4

I have a series of movieclips containing both bitmaps and text.
After applying some 3d transformations and moving in 3d space, my text and bitmaps are slightly blurred. This is AFTER I reset  all the 3d coordinates (ie z=0, rotationX=0, rotationY=0)
Has anyone else encountered this? Is there a solution to get my crisp text and bitmaps back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you set the matrix3D property to null on any objects that you've applied 3D transformation to.

Comment: Yeah sure sounds great, but then you lose your 3D transform.

Comment: This breaks your 3DTransform which you probably need.

Answer (score 2):

this is a very interesting error.

the blur that appears is actually improper anti-aliasing, or smoothing that is usually solved by rendering the font with fine colors along the edges.  in this case, it is in fact caused by 3D transformations and can be solved by nullifying the `matrix3D` after the animation:

```
myTextContainer.transform.matrix3D = null;
```

you could also write:

```
myTextContainer.transform.matrix = new Matrix();
```

but with this approach you'll have to import `flash.geom.Matrix`.

both options will also reset to zero the `x` and `y` coordinates, and possibly other important settings of the animated display object, so **you'll also have to assign those values to variables and reapply them after nullifying the transform matrix**.

it seems that once a font is transformed, it loses this fine color tinting.  non transformed fonts have these color details while transformed fonts become completely desaturated.

attached is a zoomed in detail of 12 point font which exhibits this loss of color detail.  the top string has no 3D transformation while the bottom string was animated onto the stage via `rotationY`.

[image]

here is the same image saturated to 90% to show the colors more clearly:

[image]

these color details are easier to see on grey text.

i believe this error has been present since Flash Player 9 / AVM2 was first introduced.  additionally,  the fine color detail around the properly rendered font was much more saturated in early versions of the Flash player, which, in my opinion, made the fonts look much better - although the difference could be considered negligible by non perfectionists unlike myself.

Comment: This is still an issue in Adobe Animate - Flash player 25........Thank you for the solve.

Answer (score 0):

Looking up another post on 3d issues and came across the solution.
You need to remove all 3d transformations by applying a new transfrom.matrix

var tempMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
            this.transform.matrix = tempMatrix;

Comment: The blurring will have been caused by cumulative rounding errors in the matrix maths. I've noticed a similar effect in Silverlight too.

Answer (score 0):

An Even better answer is to use this fix.  It's one I used to use all the time.

```
    /**
     * Fixes the slight distortion that occurs when an object has a 3D transform associated with it.
     * @param   di:DisplayObject    The DisplayOjbect to fix.
     */
    public function fix3DBlur(di:DisplayObject):void {
        di.scaleX = di.width / (di.width - 1);
        di.scaleY = di.height / (di.height - 1);
    }
```

This function sets a slightly offset scaleX and scaleY.  It seems weird, but they when you make 3d adjustments to the object using any 3d property it keep it from looking blurry.  You can always remove the 3DTransform, but sometimes you need it to stay in place.

I place this function on a Utilities3D class I have.